# Azure Web App Working Memory Set vs App Service Plan Memory Usage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, performance-testing

I am doing performance testing for my API hosted in Azure App Service. My API response time is increasing whenever there is a spike in the Working Memory Set graph. But my app service plan is showing 50-55% of memory with only one instance running.

Can you clarify to me, why API response time is increasing every time there is a spike in the 'Working memory Set' even though my app service plan memory is only around 50%?

[Response Time Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAt4c.png)

[image: Response Time Graph]

[Working Memory Set Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF752.png)

[image: Working Memory Set Graph]

Answer (score 0):

This is tough to answer without accessing your site logs but in general your api is consuming resources when it's called and then resting again. Similar to how your heartrate would increase when you start running but should return to normal when you stop again.

Is the response time not within your allowed time range? What is the experience from the customer side? Performance testing on cloud environments can be a slippery slope.

I would suggest using the built in [Diagnose and Solve blade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics) of your web app, which has the same troubleshooting tools a support engineer would use to assist you in a paid technical support ticket. This should help tell you if there are any issues with your site that might be impacting performance.

Also, please note that if you're running on the free or shared tier that perf testing is not really applicable as we do not support running production apps on those tiers.